# simple code with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, c

I am new to the objective c and i write the code according to a reference book.
but something went wrong and I don't know why.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    if (argc==1){
        NSLog(@"you need to provide a file name");
        return (1);
    }

    FILE *wordFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char word[100];

    while(fgets(word , 100, wordFile)){
        word[strlen(word)-1] = '\0';

        NSLog(@"the length of the %s is %lu", word, strlen(word));
    }
    fclose(wordFile);

    return 0;
}
```

the tool indicates that the `while` part went wrong, `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.
Any idea?

Comment: Have you checked if wordFile is null? if the file does not exist, or the path you give is wrong, the file may be null.

Comment: @MByd you should write your comment as answer, seems like the only place it can go wrong.

Answer (score 4):

It compiles and runs fine on my machine.  But imagine you have an empty line in your file.  Then `strlen(word)` will return zero.  Hence `word[strlen(word)-1] = '\0';`  will try to set some memory which might not be valid since word[-1] might not be a valid memory cell, or a memory cell that you can legally access.

Oh, and by the way, it has nothing to do with objective-c.  This is mostly (but for the NSLog call) pure ansi C.

Comment: More over, the {fgets} function automagically appends a null character at the end making the statement redundant anyway. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/